# shiny: get the underlying reactive value on the server side

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to get the value of a reactive input on the server side. How can I do this?

I tried the following:

```
# shinyServer code
rv <- reactive( as.integer( input$value ) ) # integer input value
print(rv)
```

However, this does not print the underlying value of the reactive.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reactives you can access like this:

```
observe({
    print(rv())
})
```

Comment: hello, when I try to call it like a function I get the folllowing error `Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.`

Comment: well, without more code we can only guess. You get that error because you did not wrap it in an observer, i make an edit.

Comment: It works! Thanks :) Why do I need to enclose the print() statement in an observer ?

Comment: Well, i can only share my understanding. Shiny is great, because you can have reactivity on variables. Now you could say every value in server.R should be reactive (your argument?). But you could need different kinds of reactivity, you might want to update inputs or outputs or just (reactive) values within server.R and there reactivity might has to be restricted on conditions (e.g. only update if input$a changes, but not if input$b). So you will have to tell what kind of reactivity you want, in your case no return value but message to JS, which can be achieved with observe().